# Чем является &$count в PHP-функции str_replace?

Tags: php

Сначала, я посчитал, что параметр *count* в функции *str_replace* является лимитом количества замен (т.е. сколько раз надо найти и заменить, thanks cap), но когда просмотрел пример в официальной документации, возникли сомнения. **Так для чего же нужен этот параметр?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count

> If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

Или по-русски. Если передана, то получит количество выполненных замен.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь count передаётся в переменной. - Это отклик о произведённых заменах. Если это значение 0, то ничего не найдено и нет замен.
Хотя, если бы count и мог отражать лимит, тогда он назывался бы термином quanta.
А если ещё к параметрам функции добавить бы параметр rban - "разрешать|запрещать" повторные замены, и в заключение - тот самый count со своим предназначением ...  - тогда настоящая функция str_replace() смотрелась бы солиднее и без предъявленных выше вопросов.